# How to find a missing button on windows form without too many changes?

Tags: c#, button, user-controls, window, windows

What can I use to view all the controls on a form if everything is overlapping each other etc. Don't want to touch it yet, just view, make sure they're there.

Comment: Are the buttons missing at design time or at run time? Is there any need to find the button at all, if you found the events you should be able to work with this code.

Comment: If you aren't using a version control system then is there any reason why you can't make a copy of the appropriate files - then edit & change as much as you need - then restore from the copies.

Comment: I can't see them in either design or run time. Their missing on her branch, and our QA enivornment, as her work has been merged thereto. Yeah I need it to move it back to where it was. Our senior developer moved stuff around before she left, just to annoy us, so instead of reverting the changes, I just need to fix stuff. PaulF, we work with Visual Studio Team Services and GIT but I don't want to mess around with stuff as I don't have the knowledge for that yet, and I'm working straight to the production branch so I need to be careful what I do... Stressed out!\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "Document Outline" window (view ==> other windows ==> Document Outline) to see all control inside the form and select them from there.

Comment: Great, thank you, I appreciate the quick guide. Didn't even know about it. Thanks Skyqula.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Document outline in visual studio.
`View - Other Windows - Document outline` or `ctrl + alt + t`. It should show you win form controls structure.